# How can I use PHP to detect duplicate files if they may have different names and hashes?

Tags: php, sorting, duplicates

Okay, so here's my situation. I have a long, long list of files (over 100,000) and I know that at least a few hundred are duplicates. Here's the problem: the dupes came from different sources so they not only hash differently, but they have slightly different filenames as well.

An example would be to think song titles. Say I have 
"Phil Collins - You Can't Hurry Love.mp3"
"You Cant Hurry Love by Phil Collins.mp3"
"Phil Collins - Some Live Album - Can't Hurry Love (Live).mp3"

The first two are virtually identical but were ripped from different sources, so they don't hash the same. I only need to hang on to one of them.

So basically I need PHP (since I have no other programming experience) to be able to compare these files, somehow know that the first two are the same but the third one is not. Basically, I'm having trouble even wrapping my head around trying to solve this problem let alone being able to troubleshoot any actual code. I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: Do the mp3 files contain ID3 tag with appropriate title and artist information?

Comment: No, of course not. That'd make this too easy! And the mp3 thing is just an example and not the actual use case, but nevertheless there is no kind of metadata that I can use.

Comment: Your best bet is probably going to be to come up with a "probability" of two files being a match and focusing on higher probability entries. A full match on names and/or hashes would of course result in a higher probability. You might even extract individual "words" from filenames and use percentage of words those filenames have in common as a lower but still reasonably high probability. There are plenty of metrics you can possibly use, but you won't be able to have a 100% degree of confidence, so you'll want to have a way to focus on likely matches and do a manual review where necessary.

Comment: What B.Fleming commented is right. It is not possible to actually see the files are identical because if they ripped from different sources, they won't be the same file. It seemed you also have multiple version of the song. Thus, even if you sound analyze the song, it won't match unless they are the same version. One of the method is that if the file have the same general naming context. You can try getting out the artist name. Remove the album part if it have, also the (live version) part. Then generalize their spelling using a dict. For example, cant with can't. No guarantee though,so backup